# Excel / LibreOffice Calc: find item in column with latest first occurrence?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sorting, openoffice-calc

In a Calc or Excel sheet I have a column with bunch of names. Each name can occur one or multiple times.

Each name has a 'first occurrence' i.e. the first row in which it appears.

I'm looking for an expression or formula to find the name with the *latest* first occurrence.

An example to clarify:

|  | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice |
| 2 | Charlie |
| 3 | Bob |
| 4 | Eve |
| 5 | Charlie |
| 6 | David |
| 7 | Bob |
| 8 | Alice |
| 9 | David |
| 10 | Charlie |
| 11 | Eve |

`David` first occurs is row 6, all other names appear earlier (and also again further down, but I'm only interested in their first occurrence). So in this case the name I want is `David`.

I can probably think of a very over-engineered solution with spare columns and sorting mechanisms, but I feel there's probably an easier way to do this.

Comment: The example would be easier to use as text instead of an image. However, the question is clear.

Comment: @JimK Thanks, wasn't really familiar with how to edit tables in markdown, hopefully this makes the question more useful for others in the future.

Comment: Very nice table. I was expecting you to simply indent the text, but that works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For LibreOffice, enter the following as an [array formula](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html).

```
=INDIRECT("B"&2+MAX(MATCH(B3:B13;B$3:B$13;0)))
```

To avoid array formulas, use SUMPRODUCT instead.

```
=INDIRECT("B"&2+SUMPRODUCT(MAX(MATCH(B3:B13;B$3:B$13;0))))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's indeed a lot more compact that I could have imagined :) I'm unfamiliar with array formulas as well as `sumproduct` and `match` and the `indirect` syntax. From the context I can sortof grasp what they each do but I'll look into it to fully understand. Thanks again, this helps a lot, very insightful!

Answer (score 0):

For Excel, just use:

```
=XLOOKUP("*", UNIQUE(B1:B11), UNIQUE(B1:B11), , 2, -1)
```

It does not automatically sort the list, so the last item from `UNIQUE()` is also the last "first instance of a new name" on the list. Then using `XLOOKUP()` to look for `anything` by looking for `"*"` (need the doublequote characters) with "2" for the 5th parameter so it knows that's a wildcard, and "-1" for the last parameter so it looks from the end so it will find the last such name does the trick.

The key to it all is `UNIQUE()` generating the list, then NOT sorting it. Very aggravatingly (usually) it does not. But for your case here, that is a nice thing all around.